# Reseting a Javascript Class to its Default values

Tags: javascript, class

Pretty silly question, but I was thinking about this randomly earlier and I've never tried doing it... let's say I have a class like so:

```
function Drug () {
  this.name = '';
  this.type = '';
}
```

Later on in the page I set some values to this Drug:

```
var drug = new Drug();
drug.name = 'Testing';
drug.type = 'TestType';
```

**Is there a simple way to let's say restart this instance of Drug to its defaults *without* just doing something like:**

```
var drug2 = new Drug();
```

Like some sort of **reset** function I can create inside of `Drug` to just do `drug.reset();` ?

I tried: `this.clear = function () { return new Drug(); }` but that doesn't do the trick...

Comment: What does `Drug.call(drug)` do? http://jsfiddle.net/dRBpm/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're overthinking it just a little. Instead of directly initializing those properties in the constructor, create an `init()` method which initializes them, called by the constructor. You can then call it to reinitialize the object's properties.

```
function Drug () {
  this.init();
}
Drug.prototype.init = function() {
  this.name = '';
  this.type = '';
}

// Instantiate:
var d = new Drug();
d.name = 'Testing';
console.log(d);
// Drug {name: "Testing", type: ""}

// Re-initialize it
d.init();
console.log(d);
// Drug {name: "", type: ""}
```

This certainly isn't the only way you could handle it, but the first that comes to mind.

Comment: Ahh very true! Yeah I thought I was thinking about it too much haha. I had never needed to do this, just out of sheer curiosity I tried, and I realized I couldn't do it that way! Thanks so much, makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

With this way you can redifine later your default values or add/remove them

```
function Drug() {
  this.init();
}

// initializer
(function(obj) {
  obj.prototype.init = function() {
    for ( var k in obj.prototype ) {
      this[ k ] = obj.prototype[ k ];
    }
  }
}(Drug));

// define here all default properties
Drug.prototype.name = '';
Drug.prototype.type = '';



var drug = new Drug();
drug.name = 'Testing';
drug.type = 'TestType';

console.log( drug );
drug.init();
console.log( drug );
```

try it yourself here: http://jsfiddle.net/bukfixart/vzsFw/

Comment: Very nice, I like it! Any reason for putting the prototype in it's own self executing function? Seems like a good idea though!

Comment: it allows you to copy this code by just changing the parameter (`Drug` in this case) for other reuse. so it also can be encapsulated into an extern function

Comment: Oh very nice, definitely would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

A rather general form of providing publicly-accessible properties in a class.

From here, you could build in a config object (in the constructor), to run overtop of the defaults.

```
var Drug = function (cfg) {
    var defaults = {
        key : "val"
    };

    this.init = function () {
        var key, val;
        for (key in defaults) {
            if (defaults.hasOwnProperty (key)) {
                val = defaults[key];
                this[key] = val;
            }
        }
        if (cfg) {
            for (key in cfg) {
                if (cfg.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                   val = cfg[key];
                   this[key] = val;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    this.reset = this.init;

    this.init();
};
```

Here `.reset()` is just sugar on top of `.init()`.
If you wanted, though, you could have the application of defaults and the application of config separated, so that `.reset()` ignored the config and just used defaults...

There are a billion ways of doing this, but here's one that would let you keep private state of this particular created object, while resetting the publicly-exposed properties.